# Creating a less linear flow of activities

Tags: android

I'm new to android development, and have set myself the task of creating a contact management application - just for the purpose of improving my skills.

The user has all the usual contact editing options available to them - find contact, new contact, edit contact, delete contact, etc. Each of these works in their own right - 'find contact' will 'select' the appropriate contact (store their ID in a public variable). If you press 'edit' or 'delete' whilst a contact is 'selected' then those functions work as they should.

But what happens when the user tries to press 'edit' or 'delete' when there is no contact selected? The simple solution would be to display the message 'please select a contact', but that is bad design. If the app needs user input, then they should be re-directed to the necessary activity to select a contact.

So when the user clicks the 'Edit' button, I wrote this very small snippet of code:

```
public void findContact(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FindContactActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);      
}

public void editContact(View view)
{
    if (Db.contact == null)
        findContact(null);
    else {
        // navigate to edit activity
    }
}
```

In this case, 'contact' is an object of type `contact`, which stores contact related information in it's own class. `Db` is a class that contains my database access functions - it seemed like a good spot to store a public variable that would need to be accessible from anywhere.

Now the code above obviously works fine. If a contact is selected, great - we go to the edit screen. If not, we go to the find-contact screen. But the problem is what happens once the user has selected a contact? It doesn't take them back to the edit screen again.

My ideal flow would be, in pseudo-code:

```
editContact()
{
    if (contact is selected)
        editContact();
    else
    {
        findContact();
        // once found, go to edit contact screen
        editContact();
    }
}
```

Bearing in mind I am brand new to android development, I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers on creating the 'flow' of the application, as described above.

Comment: What's the problem with going to the edit contact screen after finding one?

Comment: Because the find contact screen may be navigated to under different circumstances, not just when the user is trying to edit them.

Comment: Ok, I have posted an answer that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem there could be several ways to do it. I would probably simply disable the "Edit" `Button` if they haven't selected a contact yet because they shouldn't be able to try and edit if nothing is selected. However, if this doesn't work for you then you could pass a flag with your `Intent`. One thing I do sometimes is to pass a "source" flag.

After clicking edit and no contact is selected

```
Intent i = new Intent(Edit.this, FindContact.class);
i.putExtra("source", "edit");
startActivity(i);
```

then in your find contact get the extra

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if ("edit".equals(intent.getStringExtra("source");
{
     // create intent for EditScreen
```

You also could simply pass a `boolean` value this way with key "edit" and check if that is true. If so, then go to `EditScreen` if not go wherever you need to. I hope this helps. Let me know if I misunderstand.

You also will find different [Intent.FLAGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) very valuable

Answer (score 1):

Actually android has a philosophy around the "flow" of activities which is covered [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) 
Since you are a new android developer it's mandatory to understand how activities are working.

By the info in your question it seems that you are not following android guidelines which is not necessarily a bad thing but you must have valid reasons not to. So by the programmatic view of your question I suggest that you disable the edit and delete buttons when a contact is not selected or if you prefer, to restrict user's choices based on the data selected or displayed.

However you are asking about the "flow" so my advice here is to study more about activities and how the back stack is working and look at the sdk examples. In most of the applications that a user can make some actions based on data selected those actions are presented to the user after a longclick on a record. In your case a pseudo flow would be something like this:

Find Activity --> Results --> Click on a Result --> Choices List (Edit, Delete e.t.c) -->  Edit or Delete Activity (after edits goes back to Results)

Now about "creating a less linear flow of activities" IMO is a little too generic. You can control the flow of your activities as you want by using either the techniques in the design (look my link on top) or by code by using for example the finish method which removes the activity from the back stack.

Hope this helps...